# Does the Lorentz transformation for EM-fields address something more fundamental?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electric-fields, charge, inertial-frames

When a tiny spherical charged particle (having a conductive surface) moves at a relativistic speed, the Lorentz transformation for EM-fields predicts that its electric field increases at the top and bottom of the charge whether or not it has been made of something conductive, whereas the field decreases at the left- and right-hand sides along the motion direction.

[image: Relativistic charge]

On the other hand, we know that as the tiny spherical charge moves at a considerable portion of the speed of light, its geometrical shape shifts to a spheroid. Taking account of the fact that the charge density is no longer uniform and it increases at the top and bottom of the spheroid, I want to know whether it is the new arrangement of the charged particles that implies the electric field to be like that shown in the figure for the relativistically moving charge, or the Lorentz transformation predicts the EM-field independent of the charge distribution. Remember that the electric field of a charged conductive spheroid is very similar to that predicted by the Lorentz transformation, however, I do not know how far they match.

Answer (score 3):

The fields you describe are for an idealized point charge, without any substructure.  The difference in intensity is solely due to the motion of the charge.

Also, note that the field due to a small ellipsoid is approximately equal to that of a point charge for distances significantly greater than the size of the ellipsoid.  This can be seen by expanding the field in a multipole series;  at large distances, the monopole term is dominant, and the monopole term is spherically symmetric.  So at large distances, the electric field of an ellipsoid (or any other charge configuration) does not vary with angle;  and so the angular dependence of the moving charge cannot be due to any sort of relativistic contraction of the charge configuration.

Comment: Thought-provoking answer! So, do you mean that there is no new charge distribution on the moving conductive sphere as measured by the lab observer?

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry No, I don't mean that.  The Lorentz contraction would cause the sphere to have a different charge distribution measured in the lab.  But this new charge distribution is not responsible for the properties of the electric field you were asking about.  To put it another way:  If we simply "squashed" a static charge mechanically, so that it had an ellipsoidal shape but was still at rest, it would have a roughly symmetric electric field at large distances, not the "squashed" electric field that you're asking about.

Comment: Remember that I mean a charge distribution due to the *motion* of electric charges resulting in a surface current rather than due to, solely, the Lorentz contraction: *charges at sharp points in the geometry will be considerably higher than in comparatively flat surfaces.*

Answer (score 2):

The Lorentz transformation is sufficient to find the contracted field in the lab frame. It does not matter whether the charge is concentrated on a sphere, or at a single point - the field of a moving charge is always contracted the same. The field contraction is due to motion of the charge, not due to deviation of the charge density from spherical symmetry.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no new charge distribution? If so, why the contracted (Lorentz) field cannot move the charges into a new arrangement as far as the Lorentz field is not exactly the same as that we anticipate of a stationary charged spheroid according to @MichaelSeifert answer?

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at. Charge distribution does depend on the motion; the sphere contracts and the charge is distributed differently. My answer says the field contracts as well and can be determined from the field in the other frame. It is not necessary to find the new contracted charge distribution first.

Comment: If the charge is distributed differently, it produces an electric field that (according to @MichaelSeifert answer) slightly differs from that predicted by the Lorentz transformation, which seems not to be rational since two different fields cannot be attributed to our moving charge. 

On the other hand, if such new distribution exists and it produces a field exactly compatible with that predicted by the Lorentz transformation, the lab observer does not agree with the observer standing on the sphere regarding the number of, say, electrons accumulated on a specific surface of the sphere.

Comment: I don't think his answer implies that at all. There is only one field at any frame, and it can be determined either from the rest frame field via the Lorentz transformation, or via the Maxwell equations based on the contracted charge distribution.

Comment: If the charge distribution is a set of point charges, then number of these point charges is the same in all frames.

Comment: How can it be possible when you agree that the charge distribution is different from the standpoint of the two observers? Assume the sphere moves very close to the speed of light, then its shape changes to an infinitesimally thin bar. Then, the new charge distribution gathers the entire number of charges on top and bottom of the bar so that the charge distribution is nearly zero on the left- and right-hand sides of the bar as measured by the lab observer.

Comment: However, the observer at rest WRT the sphere asserts that there is a non-zero number of charges uniformly distributed everywhere on the surface of the sphere.

Comment: There is no contradiction. The number of the point charges is the same in all frames, but their positions are different, and that's why the charge distribution is different.

Comment: Yes, the total number of charges remains the same, however, the number of charges in an arbitrarily chosen area (with a *specific* magnitude) is different from the viewpoint of the observers. Consider an area $a×a$ on the sphere. The observer at rest on the sphere says that the electrons *A*, *B*, and *C* are detected within this area, however, the lab observer says that, say, only *A* and *B* are available in the said area and the electron *C* is missing!

Comment: That's because mutual distances of the electrons are different in the lab frame, the distribution is contracted, they are closer to each other, so density (number of electrons per unit volume, or area) comes out higher.

Comment: So there would be more electrons per unit area, not less, in the lab frame.